# What is the best way to return a PDF via a DotNet webservice?

Tags: .net, web-services, pdf

We've had a web service that's been operating without issue for years now, returning PDFs as a byte array. As we're about to increase the volume to the web service, I was wondering if there might be a better way out there?

Typically, the PDFs will range in size from 100kb-2mb.

Our clients run the gamut from java of various flavors to DotNet.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I take you do know about optimizing the PDF so the pages ordered.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDFs are static then you may want to look at putting them on a CDN and using a tokenised system for access, then the PDFs are sent to the end point closest to your users and are designed to be scalable.

If not then you probably want to compress them if you can (PDF optomization normally does a good job of this though), but serving up from multiple web servers (i.e in a web-farm) is probably a good start.

Comment: The PDF is being built on the fly (parts extracted from a larger PDF, then optimized) before being sent via the webservice.